# Unable to use spring tests with async + spring security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

I have a `@RestController` class that returns `DeferredResult` objects from its' endpoints. Prior to reaching these endpoints, I use a `@EnableWebSecurity` class to set up basic authetication. I am able to curl these endpoints locally with the correct basic auth and get it to work. However, testing these endpoints via spring tests results in this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$SecurityContextAsyncContext cannot be cast to org.springframework.mock.web.MockAsyncCont

I've tried using `@WebAppConfiguration` and `@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringSecurityConfig.class)` annotations on my test class and setting up the `MockMvc` myself (`SpringSecurityConfig` is just my class which implements basic auth). I've also tried just using `@SpringBootTest` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`.

Here's my current test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringSecurityConfig.class)
public class PushNotificationControllerSpringTest {

    @MockBean
    BucketDetailsService bucketDetailsService;

    @MockBean
    NotificationService notificationService;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void prepare() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).apply(springSecurity()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testListBulletins() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(
                mockMvc.perform(get("/admin/bulletins").header("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3cwcmQ="))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn()));
    }
}
```

And here is my rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class PushNotificationController {

    protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PushNotificationController.class);

    @Autowired
    BucketDetailsService bucketDetailsService;

    @GetMapping("/bulletins")
    public DeferredResult<List<BulletinDetails>> listBulletins() {
        DeferredResult<List<BulletinDetails>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
        logger.debug("Fetching bulletins...");
        bucketDetailsService.listBulletins()
                .whenComplete((res, ex) -> setResult(deferredResult, res, ex, "List bulletins"));
        return deferredResult;
    }

    private Throwable getRootCause(@NotNull Throwable throwable) {
        Throwable ex = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(throwable);
        return ex == null ? throwable : ex;
    }

    protected <T> void setResult(DeferredResult<T> deferredResult, T res, Throwable ex, String prefix) {
        if (ex != null) {
            ex = getRootCause(ex);
            logger.debug("{} failure - exception: ", prefix, ex);
            deferredResult.setErrorResult(ex);
        } else {
            logger.debug("{} successfully completed - response: {}", prefix, res);
            deferredResult.setResult(res);
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: complete stacktrace added after comment

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$SecurityContextAsyncContext cannot be cast to org.springframework.mock.web.MockAsyncContext
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at net.rakugakibox.spring.boot.logback.access.LogbackAccessSecurityAttributesSaveFilter.doFilter(LogbackAccessSecurityAttributesSaveFilter.java:28)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:165)
    at com.bbmtek.ops.admin.partner.contribution.springtest.PushNotificationControllerSpringTest.testGetClients(PushNotificationControllerSpringTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: can you update your post with entire stacktrace ?

Comment: Added it now, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug that has been fixed in Core Spring.

See [SPR-16695](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16695) for details.

If you upgrade to Spring Framework 4.3.16, 5.0.6, or higher, the problem should go away.

If it does not go away with an upgrade, please create a new [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) to describe the problem.

Comment: I have not upgraded to try this yet, but I see the issue and the solution in your link, so I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

update your test

```
 @Test
 public void PushNotificationControllerSpringTest() throws Exception {

 ....

 MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/admin/bulletins").header("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3cwcmQ="))
    .andExpect(request().asyncStarted()).andReturn();

     this.mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult)).andExpect(status().isOk());
 }
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it did not change the error. I believe Sam is correct.